# How ORM works in CakePHP3

Tags: cakephp, orm, cakephp-3.0

I am confused about how we can effectively create code using the ORM in CakePHP3.

I have 2 months of experience in CakePHP2 and now on I wish to move on to CakePHP3, but I am confused about some basics of CakePHP3:

1. How does the ORM work in CakePHP3?
2. How is CakePHP3 more effective than CakePHP2?

I've already read Cookbook 3.x from the official CakePHP site, but I am still confused.

I am new to the ORM concept. Please could I have help to figure out the basics of an ORM, why we use it in CakePHP3, and how using the ORM can be more effective and generates less code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I recommend you do [the blog tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/blog.html) - and then revisit your question.

Comment: already red blog tutorial and cookbook 3.x from official site..but unable to understand why we use ORM in cakephp3.and also want to know how ORM will help to make code effective and short and how we make less coding and give effective output compared to cakephp 3.x using ORM?

Comment: i already do the blog tutorial and also make sample small web application using cakebook 3.x..but it seems like some functions and methods name are changed compared to cakephp2.x..while the lines of code remains same..so i wonder why we used cakephp3 while line of code remain same compared to old version..if there is some usefullness of ORM in cakephp3 then let me know.

Comment: You should clarify by editing the question what you do know about the new ORM (and put anything you've added as comments _in_ the question). Right now the question is vague and too broad, I've answered my understanding of your comments.

Comment: yes ,you are right..i doesnt know how ORM works and also new to cakephp.if you know about some good tutorials of cakephp3 or something from which i will learn cakephp3 basics, then please send me links....thanks for your valuable time and suggestions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is covered [in some detail in the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/orm-migration.html#new-orm-upgrade-guide) (emphasis added):

> CakePHP 3.0 features a new ORM that has been re-written from the
>   ground up. While the ORM used in 1.x and 2.x has served us well for a
>   long time it had a few issues that we wanted to fix.
>
> - Frankenstein - Is it a record, or a table? Currently it’s both.
> - Inconsistent API - Model::read() for example.
> - No query object -
>     Queries are always defined as arrays, this has some limitations and
>     restrictions. For example it makes doing unions and sub-queries much
>     harder.
> - Returns arrays - This is a common complaint about CakePHP, and
>     has probably reduced adoption at some levels.
> - No record object - This
>     makes attaching formatting methods difficult/impossible.
> - Containable -
>     Should be part of the ORM, not a crazy hacky behavior.
> - Recursive -
>     This should be better controlled as defining which associations are
>     included, not a level of recursiveness.
> - DboSource - It is a beast, and
>     Model relies on it more than datasource. That separation could be
>     cleaner and simpler.
> - Validation - Should be separate, it’s a giant
>     crazy function right now. Making it a reusable bit would make the
>     framework more extensible.
>
> **The ORM in CakePHP 3.0 solves these and
>   many more problems**.  The new ORM focuses on relational data stores right now. In the future and through plugins we will add non relational stores like ElasticSearch and others.

The documentation goes on with more details about the architecture of the ORM, it is worth the time to read and absorb.

If you've only spent a little time working with CakePHP 3.0 the benefits may not be apparent, but the separation of table from entity makes the responsibilities of classes/methods more obvious and adds flexibility that wasn't possible with the way the model layer previously worked.

The best way to understand the benefits of the new ORM are simply to use it, as designed.

Comment: atleast cakephp 2 orm not having method like this `$articles->find('all')
    ->where(['Articles.created >' => new DateTime('-10 days')])
    ->contain(['Comments', 'Authors'])
    ->limit(1);` or  `$articles->find('all')
    ->where(['Articles.created >' => new DateTime('-10 days')])
    ->contain(['Comments', 'Authors'])
    ->first();` .. can you explain why to get the first row using custom where have to be limit(1) or first() after getting find('all')